# iPhone-MPMediaPlayer disable seek forward button

Tags: iphone, forward, seek, mpmediaplayercontroller

I would like to remove or disable the seek forward button from the MPMediaPlayer.
I have tried to enumerate all the views but apparently I could not find this button.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: provide some code or more information what you are actually doing...

Comment: I am presenting an MPMediaPlayerViewController in order to play a movie. It is imperative to prevent the user to fast forward to movie. But the backward and play/pause functions must work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way I found is to add a transparent button over the seek forward button.
Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(535, 599, 90, 60)];
    else
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(407, 855, 90, 60)];

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button setAlpha:0.7];
    [button setTag:1200];

    [self.moviePlayer.view addSubview:button];
    [button release];
}


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.moviePlayer.view viewWithTag:1200];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(535, 599, 90, 60)];
    }
    else
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.moviePlayer.view viewWithTag:1200];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(407, 855, 90, 60)];
    }
}
```

This is for IPAD ONLY! If you would like to do the same on iPhone, please change the position of the transparent button.

Comment: And when Apple change the position of the controller in an update, then what?

Comment: Then please find another way to do it if you don't like this answer. :P...oh, and a way accepted by Apple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could always provide a custom control panel, you can hide the default controls with

```
playerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Then add a subview containing your interface and just link buttons to play/pause start/stop rewinding, and there's an open source implementation of the variable speed slider ([OBSlider](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/01/obslider-a-uislider-subclass-with-variable-scrubbing-speed/)). You will also need to register for some MP notifications:

```
MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification
MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
```

Comment: I only need to disable the seek forward button.